# Conditional style inside an html tag

Tags: html, css, jsp, tags, styles

Is it possible to use conditional style inside  tag as shown below?

```
<body>
    <div id="InScreenAlertContainer"
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style>width=100%</style>
    <![endif]-->
    >
    ...
    </div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: You should only use conditionals to include styles or other scripts. I don't believe you can use it like that. You ought to test it using IE if you're curious.

Comment: "There's no bigger teacher than curiosity" - Try that if you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a conditional style sheet depending on which browser is used**

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Source:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml

**The JQuery `.css` method lets you specify a style that takes effect after an event**

```
//On Button Click - applies a style on click.
$('#change').click(function()
{
    $('body').css('background-color',$('#color').val()); 
});
```

Source:
[Change CSS rule at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998993/change-css-rule-at-runtime)

Comment: I want to override width property only for IE. So I don't want to use two different style sheet to just change one property.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this :**

```
  #div{
        padding: 10px; /* standard */
        padding: 17px\9; /* IE 8 and below */
        *padding: 15px\9; /* IE 7 and below */
        _padding: 16px\9; /* IE 6 */
    }
```

**OR**

```
<!--[if IE]><p>You are using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>

<!--[if IE 7]><p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 7!</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7)]><p>You are not using version 7.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]><p>You are using IE 7 or greater.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 5)]><p>You are using IE 5 (any version).</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 5.5)&(lt IE 7)]><p>You are using IE 5.5 or IE 6.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 5.5]><p>Please upgrade your version of Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if true]>You are using an <em>uplevel</em> browser.<![endif]-->
<![if false]>You are using a <em>downlevel</em> browser.<![endif]>

<!--[if true]><![if IE 7]><p>This nested comment is displayed in IE 7.</p><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

**Reference :**

[reference link 1](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer)

[reference link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890740/are-there-any-ie9-css-hacks)

[refernce link microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this, but i haven't tested it.

```
 <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style>
       .mywidht{
           width:100px;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```