# Creating a css class with a Javascript object or var

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create a css class based on a javascript object or variable?

An example would be if you had an input where you can enter a hex code. I can extract the value using javascript and set it to a var.

I can then use this var to set inline styles with javascript thus changing the color of text on the page. However is there a way I could use this var and create a css class? Rather than go through all the elements of the page and set the color, I'd rather add a class on one element of the page that then have the styles nested within that class to cascade to other elements.

Comment: Use css Variables - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables   Caniuse: https://caniuse.com/#search=variables   (IE as usual not work)

Comment: Check out some of the CSS preprocessers like SCSS. Using JavaScript will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @user2182349 I am using SCSS. The problem is how can you set the var in SCSS to the JS variable, I don't think that is possible is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to dynamically alter css styling after page load.
If you want to make a change that is applied as if it was a normal css script you can add a style tag to the header via javascript.
eg.

```
var color = "blue" ; // from your input
var element  = document.createElement("style");
element.id = "myStyleId" ; // so you can get and alter/replace/remove later
element.innerHTML = ".myClass {color:" + color + ";}" ; // css rule
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0] ;
header.appendChild(element) ;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: You're welcome...though must acknowledge Abhishek Pandey above  (your first commenter)  -  just after posting I checked the link  provided and the answer there is almost identical.

Comment: thanks, yeh I just had a look. It's strange that I didn't find that when I was searching for this!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this buddy?
https://jsfiddle.net/BillyG83/hcek46a1/2/

made just for you, happy Friday

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test HTML</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="textBox"/>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Go"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var textBoxValue = $("#textBox").val();
        if (textBoxValue.length == 0) {
            alert("you didnt enter a value");
        } else if (textBoxValue.length < 6) {
            alert("you only entered " + textBoxValue.length + " chacters, a HEX code needs 6");
        } else if (textBoxValue.length == 6) {
            var newHEXcode = "#" + textBoxValue;
            alert("new HEX code = " + newHEXcode)
        } else {
            alert("you only entered " + textBoxValue.length + " chacters, thats too many, a HEX code needs 6");
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example if you enter hex value like `FFFF00` or `800000` or `FF0000` then it will change the background css of the text `Hello Pratik Ghag!`.

```js
$("#txtInput").change(function(){
  var color = "#"+$("#txtInput").val();
  $(".spnMessage").css("background",color);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter hex color code:</p>
<input id="txtInput" /><br>

<span class="spnMessage">Hello Pratik Ghag!</span>
```

Comment: This is what I am doing already. The question was using the var from the input to create a css class rather than an inline style as inline styles can only apply styles to it's own element and not cascade